# Issue with dividing layouts in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to divide a GridView in 80% of the screen and one button and a adView in rest 20%. Here is my XML. What is the best practice with layouting multiple elements in Android?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="10"
    tools:context="com.apptree.snapper.dashboard.DashboardActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="8"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_grid_view"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"></GridView>
    </LinearLayout>    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:weight="2"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_takeSnapButton"
            android:text="@string/singin_take_snap_button"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            />
        <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/dashboard_adView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1390609726414683/7854545655"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">
        </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

But it's not giving me that result. What I am missing?

This is the output.

[image]

Comment: use PercentRelativeLayout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this xml layout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <GridView
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_grid_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_takeSnapButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="@string/singin_take_snap_button"
        />

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/dashboard_adView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-1390609726414683/7854545655">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Screen shot

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Mahdi. One layout has gone out from screen.

Comment: @TechBee ok just a minute

Answer (score 2):

When you want to use android:weight,you have to change your layout_height code to this:

```
android:layout_height="0dp"
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm suggesting you to use **PercentRelativeLayout** for better performance

[Official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html)

[Android Authority tutorial](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/)